# Tools to measure performance of a java code & generate a graph based on the statistics when asked

Tags: java, performance

I have a requirement to calculate the performance of some java code at remote system and also a local system. I have to save this statistics in database or in files. Then after i have to represent this data by a offline by means of a graph/chart. Also, i can set a threshold dynamically and i want to see those processes that exceeds this threshold via means of notifications or some other mechanism. Also when asked to show the graph the process that exceed the threshold should be displayed with some different color for eg. if the performance graph is shown with green color, then the portions that exceed the threshold should be turned to red in the graph. I am interested in offline monitoring of the application. So, the monitored data should also persist & i should be able to provide the range in time/days/months considering which the graph should be displayed. I have to integrate this with my web-application on apache-tomcat-6.0.32.

Is there any tool that meet these requirement. Please provide me the details in brief.

Answer (score 0):

Visuam VM - http://visualvm.java.net/